# Pandas resample options

Tags: python, pandas

I looked up the documentation for the [pandas resample module](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html). While it does describe the parameters available in the function, It doesn't tell me the possible options of these parameters. For ex. the `how` parameter takes a value of `'sum'` (as shown in example), but what other values are possible, and what do these do? Similarly for `fill` parameter. Can anybody tell me/provide a link to available values of these parameters??

Answer (score 3):

A good place to start is probably [pandas tutorial](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#resampling) on times series functionality. It doesn't, however. cover the topic thoroughly.

You may also look at the [Cookbook](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/cookbook.html#resampling) there - just to find out the most of the links point to... Stack Overflow.

I found a table of the method arguments in [Python for Data Analysis](https://books.google.ca/books?id=UWlo-c4WEpAC&pg=PA313&lpg=PA313&dq=%22resample+method+arguments%22&source=bl&ots=ryFns1hqys&sig=D4IxSMoOFTrmWxJ9jCurtPvYdGU&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22resample%20method%20arguments%22&f=false).

---

As for the two particular parameters you ask:

1. `how` - can be a string denoting a common function (as `'sum'`, `'mean'`, etc.), a custom function taking arrays, and - what is probably not mentioned there - a dict of functions for specific columns in DataFrame (eg. `how = {col1: fun1, col2: fun2}`)
2. `fill_method` - can be `ffill` (aka `pad`) or `bfill` (aka `backfill`) - fills values forward or backward.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best yet documented part about new resample function might be found in the [what's new part for pandas 0.18.0](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.0/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0180-breaking-resample):

**New API:**

Now, you can write `.resample(..)` as a 2-stage operation **like `.groupby(...)`, which yields a Resampler.**

```
In [82]: r = df.resample('2s')

In [83]: r
Out[83]: DatetimeIndexResampler [freq=<2 * Seconds>, axis=0, closed=left, label=left, convention=start, base=0]
```

Downsampling

You can then use this object to perform operations. These are downsampling operations (going from a higher frequency to a lower one).

```
In [84]: r.mean()
Out[84]: 
                            A         B         C         D
2010-01-01 09:00:00  0.485748  0.447351  0.357096  0.793615
2010-01-01 09:00:02  0.820801  0.794317  0.364034  0.531096
2010-01-01 09:00:04  0.433985  0.314582  0.424104  0.625733
2010-01-01 09:00:06  0.624988  0.609738  0.633165  0.612452
2010-01-01 09:00:08  0.510470  0.534317  0.573201  0.806949
In [85]: r.sum()
Out[85]: 
                            A         B         C         D
2010-01-01 09:00:00  0.971495  0.894701  0.714192  1.587231
2010-01-01 09:00:02  1.641602  1.588635  0.728068  1.062191
2010-01-01 09:00:04  0.867969  0.629165  0.848208  1.251465
2010-01-01 09:00:06  1.249976  1.219477  1.266330  1.224904
2010-01-01 09:00:08  1.020940  1.068634  1.146402  1.613897
```

Furthermore, resample now supports getitem operations to perform the resample on specific columns.

```
In [86]: r[['A','C']].mean()
Out[86]: 
                            A         C
2010-01-01 09:00:00  0.485748  0.357096
2010-01-01 09:00:02  0.820801  0.364034
2010-01-01 09:00:04  0.433985  0.424104
2010-01-01 09:00:06  0.624988  0.633165
2010-01-01 09:00:08  0.510470  0.573201
and .aggregate type operations.

In [87]: r.agg({'A' : 'mean', 'B' : 'sum'})
Out[87]: 
                            A         B
2010-01-01 09:00:00  0.485748  0.894701
2010-01-01 09:00:02  0.820801  1.588635
2010-01-01 09:00:04  0.433985  0.629165
2010-01-01 09:00:06  0.624988  1.219477
2010-01-01 09:00:08  0.510470  1.068634
These accessors can of course, be combined

In [88]: r[['A','B']].agg(['mean','sum'])
Out[88]: 
                            A                   B          
                         mean       sum      mean       sum
2010-01-01 09:00:00  0.485748  0.971495  0.447351  0.894701
2010-01-01 09:00:02  0.820801  1.641602  0.794317  1.588635
2010-01-01 09:00:04  0.433985  0.867969  0.314582  0.629165
2010-01-01 09:00:06  0.624988  1.249976  0.609738  1.219477
2010-01-01 09:00:08  0.510470  1.020940  0.534317  1.068634
```

**Conclusion:**

you can check well documented `.groupby()` examples to get an impression what can be done after resampling (with resampled DF/Series)