# Resampling pandas dataframe of 1H candle data to 4H

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I receive data from TDAmeritrade for 1H candle data in a pandas dataframe as shown in the image below. What would be the best way to run through this dataframe and create a new one with 4H data? I'm not a programmer, just dabbling with Python for a stock program I am writing for my personal use and could use your help. Thanks in advance.

PS: I used the following code but it seems to be messing up the close value. Is there a better way?

```
ohlc_dict = {'open':'first', 'high':'max', 'low':'min', 'close': 'last'}
newdf2=df2.resample('240T').apply(ohlc_dict).dropna(how='any')
```

received dataframe of 1H candle data

[image]

Comment: You need to be clear about what you think is wrong. Show the current output closing price and the correct closing price.

Comment: I think the issue has to do with TDAmeritrade, it sends pricing data starting at 4am PST but the charts start at 1am PST, so there is a mismatch between the resampled 4H chart and the online chart from TD.

Answer (score 0):

Specify which operation to perform on your data after resampling.

```
df_new = df_old.resample("4H").mean()
```

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36495748/8255681) answer for further information.

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach:

```
def to_hourly_data(df, hours):

  column_names = ["Date", "Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Volume"]
  result_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = column_names)

  current_index = 0
  current_low = 1000000000
  current_high = 0
  total_vol = 0
  open = 0
  date = 0

  for row in df.iterrows():
    date = row[0]
    row = row[1]
    if current_index < hours:
      if current_index == 0:
        open = row['Open']
      if row['Low'] < current_low:
        current_low = row['Low']
      if row['High'] > current_high:
        current_high = row['High']
      total_vol = total_vol + row['Volume']
      current_index = current_index + 1
    else:
      close = row['Close']
      new_row = [date, open, current_high, current_low, close, total_vol]
      result_df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame([new_row],columns=result_df.columns),result_df],ignore_index=True)
      open = 0
      current_index = 0
      current_low = 1000000000
      current_high = 0
      total_vol = 0
  return result_df
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).